# PayPal MPL for android returns error ID 589023

Tags: android, paypal

i am new in android development and i have following problem in my paypal app when i hit the
pay button after successfully paypal login.

it show error like ANDROID_589023

Comment: Show the logcat so that we can get what is the error.

Answer (score 6):

The PayPal error `589023` in particular has this meaning:

> If a fractional amount is rounded due to currency conversion, funds could be lost

This means that you are providing a payment value that needs to be rounded up or down to the nearest cent/penny/[smallest unit of currency] before being submitted to PayPal ([as described here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/error-589023-when-refunding)).

If you're asking about PayPal errors in general, check out the bottom of the [PayPal Pay API Operation page](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI) for more on the errors you might encounter.