# Unable to login in paypal through developers username password

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

I made account in Paypal and I have downloaded Paypal sdk. I have  made an application and got the client id from website. Now i'm unable to login in Paypal gateway through developer id after integrating in my app.

Please help me out where i'm going wrong

**my code**

```
    try{
    Double amount=Double.parseDouble(amnt.getText().toString());
    if(amount>=62 && amount!=null && amount!=0.0){
    amount=amount/62;
    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(""+amount), "USD", "Cab Rent");        
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);

    // It's important to repeat the clientId here so that the SDK has it if Android restarts your 
    // app midway through the payment UI flow.
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "AXJjcRB6yUtJghGBgdDHmOgkL8a9Jnd0RVARU9XPGqZ_lSstEhDSkh7D9AL2");
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "");//from ui we have to design
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " An invalid payment was submitted. 1$ minimum", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }}
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Paypal_Activity", ""+e); //BLUE

    }
```

on activity result

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                // see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                // for more details.

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
    }
    else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it does not look like you are using the current version of the SDK.  I recommend you do (with slight changes to your integration).

Answer (score 2):

Hey This is my working code with the given credential of mine app...

The BuyActivity.java

```
package com.example.paypalintegration;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

public class BuyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AR.aAFjBsPf7PzEUNdhcCM3xDQBN";
    private static final String CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "claudia.burnett-facilitator@pushnd.com";
    private EditText amnt; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy);
        amnt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);

        startService(intent);
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
        Double amount=Double.parseDouble(amnt.getText().toString());
        if(amount>=62 && amount!=null && amount!=0.0){
        amount=amount/62;
        }
        PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(amount)), "NOK","Cab Rent");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                    // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                    // see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                    // for more details.
                    Toast.makeText(this,confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            Toast.makeText(this,"The user canceled.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
            Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            Toast.makeText(this,"An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

XML file activity_buy.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyItBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="onBuyPressed"
        android:text="Buy this product" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>

and the Manifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.paypalintegration"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BuyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pay_pal_integration" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

You can test my code with logine is

personal_sandbox@pushnd.com

password..

personal_sandbox

The complete code is here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f88rean6mpfaibs/PayPalIntegration.zip?m=

Answer (score 0):

From this page: [PayPal MPL for android returns error ID 589023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172512/paypal-mpl-for-android-returns-error-id-589023)

The PayPal error 589023 in particular has this meaning:

```
If a fractional amount is rounded due to currency conversion, funds could be lost
```

Perhaps you didn't round up / down to the smallest unit or cents of the currency.

**For example:**

```
(amount* fee_multiplier).round(2)
```

**Update:**
Values like $1.1 and $1.111 are unacceptable by Paypal. We need to make sure that values received in the thingToBuy has been rounded to the nearest cents and to the lowest unit of the currency.

Another example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
df.format(amount);
```

Results:

```
amount: 1.3333333 (double) -> df.format: 1.33 (new DecimalFormat)
```

Currencies like Indonesian Rupiah (IDR) do not have any decimals because their smallest unit is IDR 25

Comment: earlier (8 months before) i used the same code, transactions was done successfully

Comment: have you tried displaying the real amount before sending to paypal? Price like $12.909 (for example) are unaccepted by Paypal.

Comment: what will be the CVV for testing for sandbox mode ?

Comment: @ManishYadav yes. 1 Norwegian Krone / 1 nok to usd = $0.17.

Comment: @Yushi recently you have amount=amount/62; then the result surely results with many decimal places. Perhaps you can round the amount first before sending it to thingToBuy.

Comment: ok thanx.. now i m getting.... 'An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs'... help me out :(

Comment: PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(""+amount), "NOK", "Cab Rent");  .............   this is what i have changed in code

Comment: @Yushi, it may be that when you ran the code before, the conversion resulted in a value that didn't have a fractional part smaller than the smallest unit of conversion.

Comment: values like $1.1 and $1.111 are unacceptable by paypal. We need to make sure that values received in the thingToBuy has been rounded to the nearest cents and to the lowest unit of the currency. Example: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");`
`df.format(amount);` `amount: 1.3333333 (double) -> df.format: 1.33` . Currencies like Indonesian Rupiah (IDR) do not have any decimals because their smallest unit is IDR 25

Comment: Is this code block is correct to do Norvey transactions ?  ----> "PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(""+amount), "NOK", "Cab Rent"); "